# Trying to update record with a form, error: "The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values..."

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I'm creating a database that will be used to keep track of maintenance performed on equipment in a nursing home. I'm using MS Access 2010, and I'd say my skills are somewhere between novice and intermediate, almost entirely self-taught for this project.

The database structure is as follows:

```
tblAssetTypes: 
  TypeID (PK), 
  MaintenanceSchedule, 
  EquipmentType, 
  EquipmentSubgroup, 
  MaintenanceTime, 
  TasksRequired

tblUniqueAssets: 
  UniqueID (PK), 
  StorageLocation, 
  TypeID (FK)

tblPrevMaintRecord: 
  ID (PK), 
  UniqueID (FK), 
  DatePerformed, 
  TimePerformed, 
  MaintenanceComments
```

The UniqueID will be an identifier created by maintenance people, usually as four letters and then three numbers. I'm currently using "test001", "test002", etc.

I have a form that allows users to enter the UniqueID that has been assigned to an asset, select what kind of equipment it is, and where it is stored. 
I'm currently creating another form which I want users to be able to select from a list of pre-existing UniqueIDs and then change the location that is stored in the table. However, as it is currently set up, every time I select a UniqueID from the combobox on the form, I get the following error. This error comes up after I have selected an UniqueID, and then if I try to do anything further, such as saving the record or even trying to close the form.

> The changes you requested to the table were not successful because
>   they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or
>   relationship. Change the data in the field or fields that contain
>   duplicate data, remove the index, or redefine the index to permit
>   duplicate entries and try again.

I'm sure I probably need to give more information but I'm not sure what will be needed so I'll edit as needed.

How can I update the location information stored in `tblUniqueAssets` for a UniqueID value that already exists? Surely I wouldn't need to delete the record first and then create a new one with the previous UniqueID?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. You can update (edit) the values, but you can't change the fields that make the row unique, and you can't insert a row that would cause those unique values to be duplicated. It's pretty difficult to explain what it is you need to change, because you've not included any information (code) that shows us what you're doing now.

Comment: @KenWhite I'm not seeking to change the UniqueID or insert another record. I'm only trying to change the value in the StorageLocation field for a pre-existing record. I'm also not using any code to do this, just the fields in the form. If I need code, the guides I've tried to find have never mentioned that.

Comment: If you want users to select a UniqueID from a combobox and find the record to edit, then that control must be UNBOUND, otherwise you change data in the record that has focus. Edit question to show code that 'finds' existing record (filter form or other method). Otherwise, use intrinsic tools on ribbon and right click menu to filter, but don't change value of BOUND combobox.